# TypeError: index() missing 1 required positional argument: 'subject_slug'

Tags: python, django

I have used django  to create a blog.  Now I am trying to implement a system where each post's url will contain subject_slug/slug.  Error is as above in the title.

From the terminal the error in greater detail: response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
TypeError: index() missing 1 required positional argument: 'subject_slug'

models.py

```
    from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils.text import slugify

class Subject(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    subject_slug = models.SlugField(editable=True, max_length=200, null=False, unique=True)
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        kwargs = {
            'slug': self.slug
        }
        return reverse('subject', kwargs=kwargs)
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        value = self.subject
        self.slug = slugify(value, allow_unicode=True)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    
    class Meta:
        # Gives the proper plural name for class called subject
        verbose_name_plural = "Subjects"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.subject

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, default=1, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, related_name='blog_posts')
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, verbose_name='Subject', default=1, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)   
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(editable=True, max_length=200, null=False, unique=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        kwargs = {
            'slug': self.slug
        }
        return reverse('post_detail', kwargs=kwargs)
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        value = self.title
        self.slug = slugify(value, allow_unicode=True)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date_added']
        
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
        
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, default=1, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, related_name='comments')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    email = models.EmailField()
    body = models.TextField()
    made_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['made_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Comment {} by {}'.format(self.body, self.name)
```

urls.py

```
    from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    # Home page.
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    # A page for each subject.
    path('<str:subject_slug>/', views.subject, name='subject'),
    # A page for each post including comments related to the post.
    path('<str:subject_slug>/<str:slug>/', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
    # Not sure I need this if I am to be the only author of posts.
    path('post/new/', views.post_new, name='post_new'),
]
```

views.py

```
    from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.utils import timezone
from django.views import generic
from .models import Subject
from .models import Post
from .forms import PostForm
from .forms import CommentForm

# Create your views here.

def index(request, subject_slug):
    """All subjects to be shown automatically in navbar - in base template ideally?
    Order_by needs fixing"""
    subjects = Subject.objects.all()
    subject = get_object_or_404(subject_slug=subject_slug)
    posts = Post.objects.filter(date_added__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-date_added')
    return render(request, 'blog/index.html', {'subjects': subjects,
                                               'subject': subject,
                                               'posts': posts})

def subject(request, subject_slug):
    template_name = 'blog/subject.html'
    subjects = Subject.objects.all()
    subject = Subject.objects.get(subject_slug=subject_slug)
    posts = Post.objects.filter(date_added__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-date_added')
    return render(request, template_name, {'subjects': subjects,
                                           'subject': subject,
                                           'posts': posts})
    

def post_detail(requests, subject_slug, slug):
    template_name = 'blog/subject/post_detail.html'
    subjects = Subject.objects.all()
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, subject_slug=subject_slug, slug=slug)
    comments = post.comments.filter(active=True)
    new_comment = None
    # Comment posted
    if request.method == 'POST':
        comment_form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            
            # Create comment object but don't save to database yet
            new_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
            # Assign the current post to the comment
            new_comment.post = post
            # Save the comment to the database
            new_comment.save()
    else:
            comment_form = CommentForm()
            
    return render(request, template_name, {'subjects': subjects,
                                           'subject': subject,
                                           'post': post,
                                           'comments': comments,
                                           'new_comment': new_comment,
                                           'comment_form': comment_form})
```

base.html

```
    {% load static %}
<html>
  <head>
    <title>drsmart.info</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/blog.css' %}">
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1><a href="/">DR SMART.INFO</a></h1>
    <p>the web site for the analytical rugby fan</p>
    <p>
      <ul>
        {% for subject in subjects %}
          <li><a href="{% url 'subject' subject.subject_slug %}">{{ subject }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul> 
    </p>
    
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

index.html

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
  {% for post in posts %}
    <div>
      <h2><a href="{% url 'post_detail' post.slug %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
      <p>author: {{post.author}}, published: {{post.date_added }}</p>
      <p>{{ post.content|linebreaksbr }}</p>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Your assistance is greatly appreciated.

Roderic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `index.html`, in this line `<h2><a href="{% url 'post_detail' post.slug %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>`, second argument is missing
It should be like this

```
<h2><a href="{% url 'post_detail' post.subject.subject_slug post.slug %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
```

Edit:
In your `views.py` your  index view has an argument in the definition:

```
def index(request, subject_slug):
```

But in its respective url, there is no parameter, so it is throwing an error

```
path('', views.index, name='index'),
```

So the solution is either the view should be in this way:

```
def index(request):
```

or the url should be in this way:

```
path('<subject_slug>', views.index, name='index'),
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Sai.  I tried it.  No go.  Restarted server (hoping).  Still get:response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
TypeError: index() missing 1 required positional argument: 'subject_slug'

Comment: That has to do with `url` for index. In the url there is no argument here. `path('', views.index, name='index'),`. But in the view, you have put an argument here-  `def index(request, subject_slug):`. Either remove `subject_slug` from the view or add a parameter in the url

Comment: I have edited the answer. Please check and try this

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Sai.  I tried changing the url.  Result:  response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
TypeError: index() missing 1 required positional argument: 'subject_slug'.  Same error when I tried implementing both the url and view change together.  Changing the view only results in: File "/home/pi/dsi_ws/blog/views.py", line 15, in index
    subject = get_object_or_404(subject_slug=subject_slug)
NameError: name 'subject_slug' is not defined

Comment: Ok, don't change view. Keep the view as it is and change the url. Now in the browser make sure you enter the correct url like this : `http://127.0.0.1:8000/slug`. Here `slug` is from the Subject database. It is the variable `subject_slug` in Subject model

Comment: Ok, Sai I have tried:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/coach_evaluator/  error:  File "/home/pi/dsi_ws/blog/views.py", line 24, in subject
    subject = subject.objects.get(subject_slug=subject_slug)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'subject' referenced before assignment.  Same error for:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/referee_ranking/.  Wondering why we want a subject_slug in the index.html url.  That's where we should see posts by date for all subjects.  Posts by subject should be shown in subject.html

Comment: In views, in index view, you have this query - `subject = get_object_or_404(subject_slug=subject_slug)` and that `subject_slug` should come from url. If not from url, you need to find another way to get subject_slug for that query

Comment: Apologies, I realise the the reference to subject in the index view was there because of an error I eventually fixed with the subjects = Subject.objects.all() line.  So index is now:  def index(request):
    """All subjects to be shown automatically in navbar - in base template ideally?
    Order_by needs fixing"""
    subjects = Subject.objects.all()
    posts = Post.objects.filter(date_added__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-date_added')
    return render(request, 'blog/index.html', {'subjects': subjects,
                                               'posts': posts})  And works!

Comment: Clicking on subject shows error:  UnboundLocalError at /worldcup_ratings/
local variable 'subject' referenced before assignment  Clicking on post_detail:   FieldError at /referee_ranking/a-slightly-longer-post/
Cannot resolve keyword 'subject_slug' into field. Choices are: author, author_id, comments, content, date_added, id, slug, subject, subject_id, title

Comment: regarding the error on clicking post_detail, you querying Post object with subject_slug variable. But `subject_slug` is not an  attribute in the Post model. You need to use `subject` model for that as you have referenced subject as the foreign key

Comment: First you need to get subject_slug from `Subject` model. `subjectSlug = Subject.objects.get(subject_slug=subject_slug)` and then use `subjectSlug` to get Post object - ` get_object_or_404(Post, subject=subjectSlug, slug=slug)`

Comment: Ok Sai, I have made the changes you suggested.  Also changed def post_detail requests to request.  Error now: TemplateDoesNotExist at /referee_ranking/who-to-watch/
blog/subject/post_detail.html

Comment: Great news.  Applied your subjectSlug to subject view which now works.  Thanks.  Only the post_detail domino still to fall...

Comment: And finally, eliminated subject from:  template_name = 'blog/subject/post_detail.html' and post_detail also works!  Sai, thanks very much for all your help!

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer. Thank you

Comment: Love to Sai. How? Though.

Comment: While the blog now works, runserver is showing: blog.models.Subject.DoesNotExist:  Subject matching query does not exist.  The unhappiness seems to stem from:  line 22, in subject
    subjectSlug = Subject.objects.get(subject_slug=subject_slug)

Comment: You need to put a try except block. The error occurs because the slug doesn't exist in the database. Make sure you insert the correct records into the database